# Can F# use a constructor parameter and property initializers together?

Tags: f#

In C# I have the following code to create an object instance.

```cs
var myObject = new MyClass("paramvalue")
{
   Property1 = "value1"
   Property2 = 100
}
```

I've found the F# syntax to set the properties in the initializer like:

```ml
let myObject = MyClass(Property1 = "value1", Property2 = 100)
```

Is there also an option to supply both constructor parameter(s) and property values together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```ml
let myObject = MyClass("paramvalue", Property1 = "value1", Property2 = 100)
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors#assigning-values-to-properties-at-initialization) for another example.